# Multiple commands produce… hermes

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

#### Description

I just cloned my project, installed everything with `yarn` and `pod install` and when I run the project I get a `Multiple commands produce ... hermes.framework` error.

The error output:

```
Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs

Create build description
Build description signature: 2e78cab04f15c8767559401b0ac7acaf
Build description path: /Users/theobouwman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MomoApp-eiwjjdoutbjvuqghlrgnoaydnogo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/2e78cab04f15c8767559401b0ac7acaf.xcbuilddata

note: Building targets in dependency order
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/theobouwman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MomoApp-eiwjjdoutbjvuqghlrgnoaydnogo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Momo.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework'
    note: Target 'MomoApp' (project 'MomoApp') has copy command from '/Users/theobouwman/dev/projects/momo/momo-app/ios/Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework' to '/Users/theobouwman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MomoApp-eiwjjdoutbjvuqghlrgnoaydnogo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Momo.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework'
    note: That command depends on command in Target 'MomoApp' (project 'MomoApp'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'MomoApp' from project 'MomoApp')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'MomoApp' from project 'MomoApp')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'MomoApp' from project 'MomoApp')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'MomoApp' from project 'MomoApp')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/theobouwman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MomoApp-eiwjjdoutbjvuqghlrgnoaydnogo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Momo.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks /Users/theobouwman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MomoApp-eiwjjdoutbjvuqghlrgnoaydnogo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MomoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MomoApp.build/Script-9B4EE5F931DC2030C70542B5.sh (in target 'MomoApp' from project 'MomoApp')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'fmt' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-bridging' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

2023-05-30 22:42:18.227 xcodebuild[70948:321613] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
2023-05-30 22:42:18.640 xcodebuild[70948:321654]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-21677/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:382
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-000E19281468801E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f9673b2f2e0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x6000028e8100>{number = 7, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2023-05-30 22:42:18.815 xcodebuild[70948:321639]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-21677/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:382
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-000E19281468801E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f9673b2f2e0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600002714000>{number = 6, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2023-05-30 22:42:18.877 xcodebuild[70948:321639]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-21677/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:382
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-000E19281468801E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f9673b2f2e0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600002714000>{number = 6, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

#### React Native Version

0.70.5

#### Output of `npx react-native info`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Memory: 23.95 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.5.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.05.22.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/theobouwman/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
    react-native: 0.70.5 => 0.70.5 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

#### Steps to reproduce

`yarn`, `pod install` and run the project.

#### Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository

[image: Screenshot 2023-05-30 at 22 48 51]

Answer (score -2):

I recommend:

- clean Derived Data `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- clean Pods `rm -rf ios/Pods`
- clean node_modules `rm -rf node_modules`
- install your deps and build again

Comment: I did this multiple times but it keeps giving the same error. I had to reset my Mac because the disk was so full and couldn't reduce the disk usage. And after I reinstalled everything, it gives this error.

Comment: Did you reinstall macOS or how are you "reset"?

Comment: Yes i did a macOS reinstall.